# jquery auto popup with data

Tags: jquery

I don't know what happen why the popup can't auto popup when i add the js in html, the js will check data to get "error"/ "expired" and will popup full screen message, anyone can help?

here is popup js:

```
(function ($) {
    $(function () {

            $.get("http://www.theonionism.com/webcontrol/check.php?client=www.theonionism.com", function(data){
                console.log(data);
                if(data == "error"){
                    alert("Web site error, please contact us");
                    return false;
                }

                if(data == "expired"){

                    $("body").append('<div class="expried-background"></div><div class="expried-nav">Website already expired, please contact us to resolve the matter.</div>');

                    $("body").css("margin", "0px");
                    $(".expried-background").css({
                    "position":"absolute",
                    "top":"0px",
                    "left":"0px",                   
                    "background-color":"black",
                    "opacity": "0.8",
                    "z-index": "99999",
                    "width": $(document).width(),
                    "height": $(document).height()
                    });

                    $(".expried-nav").css({
                        "position":"absolute",
                        "top": "45%",
                        "height":"40px",
                        "width":"100%",
                        "background-color":"#fff",
                        "z-index": "999999",
                        "font-family":"Arial",
                        "font-weight":"bold",
                        "text-align":"center",
                        "color":"red",
                        "padding-top":"20px",
                    });
                    return false;               
                }

        });

    }); 
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: remove ` return false;` and try again

Comment: Many thanks for reply, but still nothing happen... http://www.theonionism.com/webcontrol/index.php

Comment: i got it now this due to string you are matching. you have "error" & "expired" but on the page it is producing these: ("error"); & ("expired"); that is why it is not matching and not showing the popup you wanted.

Comment: just remove (jQuery) from your test.js present at end

Comment: thanks all, just try to remove 'return false;' change("error"); to "error", remove (jQuery)...but still can't work, it make me strange and distress....but anyway, thanks to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this way:

```
if(data == '("error");'){

 // do your stuff in case of error

}

and

if(data == '("expired");'){

 // do your stuff in case of expiration

}
```

Let me know **if this solves** the issue.
and please don't forget to **accept it as answer**.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

try using outside

```
function($){}() // remove it and try

$(function(){
   // put your stuff here
});
```

Comment: Many thanks for reply, but still nothing happen...
http://www.theonionism.com/webcontrol/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Hi i locally tried this and it worked the way you need:

```
$(function () {

    $.get("http://localhost/jq/1.php?client=www.get.com", function(data){
        if(data == "err"){
           alert("Data Loaded: " + data);

           $("body").append('<div class="expried-background"></div><div class="expried-nav">'+data+'Website already expired, please contact us to resolve the matter.</div>');

           $("body").css("margin", "0px");
           $(".expried-background").css({
             "position":"absolute",
             "top":"0px",
             "left":"0px",                   
             "background-color":"black",
             "opacity": "0.8",
             "z-index": "99999",
             "width": $(document).width(),
             "height": $(document).height()
             });

             $(".expried-nav").css({
               "position":"absolute",
               "top": "45%",
               "height":"40px",
               "width":"100%",
               "background-color":"#fff",
               "z-index": "999999",
               "font-family":"Arial",
               "font-weight":"bold",
               "text-align":"center",
               "color":"red",
               "padding-top":"20px"
             });
                return false;               
          }

        });

    });
```

Comment: i have echoed err on the 1.php